# PIL perspective transform, work out the (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use PIL to do a perspective transformation on an image, i have the coordinates of the corners of the image and the coordinates of where the corners of the image should end up. I am not sure how to obtain (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h) for the 'data' parameter.

I know it has something to do with this:
http://bishopw.loni.ucla.edu/AIR5/2Dperspective.html
but i am not sure what this page means.

Comment: You will need at least a primer in projective geometry to understand what's going on. In case you don't, try googling for well known transformation matrices and copy coefficients in the same positions as the matrix in the link you provided.

Comment: You might want to try slapping together a Tk GUI with 8 sliders so you can see how the parameters affect the transform. You should be able to write that without knowing what it means, and it will be a great accompaniment to whatever primer you find. But you're still going to have to learn the basics.

Comment: Try [this](http://pastebin.com/prVdtq05) for example. (Replace that hardcoded "bird.jpg" with an image you actually have, of course.)

Comment: @abarnet thank you, i tried making my own but it wasn't as effective, i realise now this is going to be much harder than i anticipated, trying to make a 3d graphics engine with no more than a high school level knowledge of transformation matrices is proving challenging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the parameters by solving the equation: T.x1 + v= x2 where x1 is the points coordinates in coordinate system 1 (original picture) and x2 is the new coordinate system (tilted or rotated or 3d). x1, x2, v are 2 by 1 vectors and T is 2 by 2 matrix. For example x1 = (x1x, x1y), x2 = (x2x,x2y) , v = (c,f) and

```
T = a b
    d e
```

If you do not know matrix algebra, you can solve this by eliminating variables. For each point you get two equations like:

```
a*x1x + b*x1y + c = x2x
d*x1x + e*x1y + f = x2y
```

If you now plug in one of the corner points. Lets say x1 = (0,1) and x2 = (0,4) you get:

```
a*0   + b*1   + c = 0
d*0   + e*1   + f = 4
```

From that you get:

```
b = -c
e = 4-f
```

Now, if you repeat this to other corner points (and use the knowledge of b = -c). You can solve numeric values for all variables.

Hint, scale your original picture coordinates to unit square (0,0), (0,1), (1,0) and (1,1) before calculating the transformation. This way you have lots of ones and zeros. The mathematical method is called gauss elimination (use google or wikipedia->gauss elimination->example of the algorithm).

Note that the data in im.tranform has six parameters (2d -> 2d transformation):

> Data is a 6-tuple (a, b, c, d, e, f) which contain the first two rows
>   from an affine transform matrix. For each pixel (x, y) in the output
>   image, the new value is taken from a position (a x + b y + c, d x + e
>   y + f) in the input image, rounded to nearest pixel.

**EDIT:** Ups, the above was for AFFINE tranformation. You were asking about PERSPECTIVE transformation. The function is the same but parameters are different. Data should be like:

> Data is a 8-tuple (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h) which contains the
>   coefficients for a perspective transform. For each pixel (x, y) in the
>   output image, the new value is taken from a position (a x + b y +
>   c)/(g x + h y + 1), (d x + e y + f)/(g x + h y + 1) in the input
>   image, rounded to nearest pixel.

So your equation is Q.x3 = x4, where original coordinate x3 is (x3x, x3y,1) and the transformed coordinate x4 is (x4x, x4y, 1) and for Q:

```
Q = a b c
    d e f
    g h 1
```

Compared to the AFFINE one, you embed the constant v into the matrix. Now your equations become:

```
a*x3x + b*x3y + c*1 = x4x    
d*x3x + e*x3y + f*1 = x4y   
g*x3x + h*x3y + 1*1 = 1
```

Solving by gauss elimination as the AFFINE transformation.